# About CGRectMake

Tags: objective-c

This will sound extremely silly and stupid, but I have touched a couple languages and they kind of messed up my sense of.... orientation or something:

In Objective-C, you can use CGRectMake(x,y,w,h) to make a rect. Cool.

So x,y set the... top left corner of the rect, or.... the center of the rect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocoa uses the Cartesian coordinate plane as its coordinate system (so (x, y) is set to the bottom-left corner). You can read more about the coordinate system in the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCIFCIHJ).

Answer (score 12):

In UIKit, (x,y) is the upper-left corner.